# Div overlapping issue in bootstrap mobile version

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a carousel, and 2 rows in bootstrap. The layout is fine in standard view but when it goes into mobile queries the page layout becomes messed up. The 2nd row seems to overlap the blue column and i am not sure why.

https://jsfiddle.net/ydcategd/

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" >
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="container-fluid box">
  <div   class="row" id="triple">
    <div class="col-lg-4 one">
      <p>123</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 two">
      <p>456</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 three">
      <p>789</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="single">
    <div class="col-lg-4 four">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 four">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 four">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `#triple{height:100%;}` which is causing the issue. You can mention heights per `col`  with `media` query.

Comment: How would i make the columns stack then with a media query?

Comment: Hope this is the solution you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/vsk59tck/1/

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue by using height:auto.

Answer (score 0):

You should target mobile devices first if you want mobile responsiveness

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div >

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="container-fluid box">
      <div   class="row" id="triple">
        <div class="col-xs-4 one">
          <p>123</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 two">
          <p>456</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 three">
          <p>789</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="single">
        <div class="col-xs-4 four">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 four">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 four">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Based on your updates check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aggjx1b/)

Comment: @123123 does it fix your issue?

Comment: Yea it fixes it but if i do this the whole layout becomes fluid and does not collapse like it should. Do i have to use separate classes? Sorry I am new to bootstrap.

Comment: Yea, targeting mobile i think makes the cutoff point way smaller but when it will eventually collapse the problem is still as i described. The orange row seems to overlap the blue one and is not at the bottom like it should be.

Comment: @123123 did you edit your old question? Do you want columns of middle rows to stack on top of each other? e.g red/blue/green or they should be in one row on mobile devices e.g red-blue-green.

Comment: Yes, they should stack RED blue green then the orange row at the bottom. I am not sure what's causing the problem. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hi, I checked the fiddle and the problem still seems to remain. it collapses to red then orange overlapping blue then green.

Comment: @123123 Sorry didn't update the fiddle by mistake. Now check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fix:

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div >

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid box">
  <div   class="row" id="triple">
    <div class="col-lg-4 one">
      <p>123</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 two">
      <p>456</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 three">
       <p>789</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="single">
  <div class="col-lg-4 four">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 four">
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 four">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
  }
  .carousel, .item, .active, .carousel-inner{
    height: 100%;
  }

  .item>div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .item:nth-child(1) > div {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
  }
  #triple{
    height: auto;
  }

  .col-lg-4  {
    height:100%;
  }
  .one, .two, .three{height: 50vh;}
  .one{ background-color:red;}
  .two{ background-color:blue;}
  .three{ background-color:green;}
  .four{ background-color:orange;}

  #single{
    height:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px){
    .one, .two, .three{height: 100vh;}
  }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsk59tck/1/